# Swift 3: Return from initializer error

Tags: swift, firebase, swift3, init, xcode8

I'm getting and error that reads: Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties.

I'm using swift 3 and xcode 8 also firebase as my backend.

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseDatabase

struct Post {

var ref: FIRDatabaseReference
var key: String!
var username: String!
var postId: String!
var postText: String!



init(username: String, postId: String, postText: String, key: String = ""){

    self.username = username
    self.postId = postId
    self.postText = postText

}//<--- im getting the error right here


init(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) {

    let values = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String,String>

    self.username = values["username"]
    self.postText = values["postText"]
    self.postId = values["postId"]
    self.ref = snapshot.ref
    self.key = snapshot.key

}

func toAnyObject() -> [String: AnyObject]{

    return ["username":username as AnyObject, "postText":postText as AnyObject,"postId":postId as AnyObject]

}


}
```

Any idea on how i can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stored property `ref` is a non-optional type.

According the rules all non-optional properties must be initialized in each provided initializer.

That means you have to assign an initial value to the property or you make the property optional.

Comment: What does that mean exactly? I have to call ref in where i call key, postText and such?

Comment: I'm sorry man I don't mean to be a pain but is there any way you can show me what you mean. Like what i have to add? I'm new to swift and everything and trying to learn it all.

Comment: WOW! never mind I figured out what you meant. I can't believe I missed that. Thank you.